# How to know if some data have no been extracted

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am extracting data from a collection in mongodb. my question is: can I somehow know a document that have no been extracted, or eve, this can happen? because I am writing every document into a file and i want to be sure that everything is there, another doubt is... Is the process of extracing data fail in a certain point can I continue the process in the point of failure? I have been checking "natural order" to manage to know where i should be continuing the process but it seems it is not an reliable order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am writing every document into a file and i want to be sure that everything is there

One way of doing this is to compare the number of documents in the collection in MongoDB with the number of entries in the file (or the number of files produced), after your process is complete.

> Is the process of extracing data fail in a certain point can I continue the process in the point of failure?

Your application submits a query, MongoDB returns the data for the query. How the data is processed is entirely up to your application. You can certainly continue processing the next document from MongoDB if your application encounters an error in processing the previous document.